# ActionItems of 2nd Fragment are only showing on both fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have two Fragments in created by `ViewPager`'s `MainAvtivity`.  I want to add ActionItemson ActionBar According to the which Fragment is active currently. I am not Adding menu items on Activity. But only the `ActionItems` of **2nd Fragment** are only showing on both fragments. 
Here is my code :

For **1stFragment** :

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_one, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchWidgetOne);
        SearchView search = new SearchView(getActivity());
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchItem.setActionView(search);
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.action_items_one:
                Intent addCrInent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class);
                startActivity(addCrInent);

                return true;
            case  R.id.action_items_two:
                Intent addStIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(addStIntent);

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }

    }
```

For **2ndFragment**:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchWidgetTwo);
        SearchView search = new SearchView(getActivity());
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchItem.setActionView(search);
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.action_items_one_secondMenu:
                Intent addCrInent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class);
                startActivity(addCrInent);

                return true;
            case  R.id.action_items_two_secondMenu:
                Intent addStIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(addStIntent);

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }

    }
```

For Both Fragments, in MY onCreate i have written this line :

```
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Here is my `menu_one.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchWidgetOne"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_course"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_two"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_student"/>
```

And Here is my `menu_second.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/searchWidgetTwo"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_one_secondMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_course"/>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_items_two_secondMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_person"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/add_student"/>
```

I have also used **`ivalidateOptionMenu()`** in **`onPageSelected()`** but in vain.